# Image caching in ionic 2 typescript like picasso

Tags: typescript, angular, cross-platform, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-img-cache
This link is for ionic 1 and i am not able to find any solution for image caching in ionic 2 with typescript.
Anybody ??

i tried this link but i am not able to understand the code
https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src

Answer (score 3):

You can use [imgcache.js](https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/)

`npm install imgcache.js --save`

and then make your own component or directive class to cache images , as [described here](https://www.ninjadevs.io/caching-images-in-ionic-2/) with examples.